# XML Schema V 1.1 Assertions not working in Xerces-J

Tags: java, xml, jar, schema, assertions

I able to validate my XML config file against it's XML V 1.1 schema in the Oxygen XML Developer Editor.

If my schema violates an assertion constraint, such as an element's number attribute being larger than than a specific value, it won't validate the xml config file.

```
<assert test="6 >= @Number" />
```

Yet, my assertions are being ignored when I parse the config file in java against the schema.

I am using Xerces-J 2.11.0-xml-schema-1.1-beta.

I am including the following jars in my project

```
cupv10K-runtime.jar
icu4j.jar
xerceslmpl.jar
sml-apis.jar
org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_2.1.1v201204060055.jar
```

Is there another jar that I need to include?

Any advice on why it is ignoring the asserts would be unbelievably helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Drew

Comment: I am referring to asserts/assertions in XML 1.1 schemas, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry! my mistake. Removing my comment.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to parse the file?

Comment: Do the assertions work when you use the Saxon schema validator? That would help to determine whether the error is in your schema or in your configuration.

Comment: Yes, the assertions work when I use the SAXON-EE validotor in Oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following command line, and I have not experienced problems in applying a **test** to an attribute of the current element:

`$ export XERCESJ=$HOME/xerces-j/xerces-2_11_0-xml-schema-1.1-beta
$ java -classpath $XERCESJ/cupv10k-runtime.jar:/usr/share/java/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor-2.1.100.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl-xsd11-2.12-beta-r1667115.jar:$XERCESJ/xml-apis.jar:$XERCESJ/xercesSamples.jar jaxp.SourceValidator -xsd11 -i my_instance.xml`

The XSD 1.1 syntax is fine, and the condition of the **test** is enforced.

Comment: Is this an answer? I can't tell if you're just posting this to link your question.

Comment: I would have made a comment, rather than provide an answer, but I do not have sufficient privilege to post a comment. My "answer" provides useful information in that I my own usage is nearly identical to that of the OP's, yet I do not have the OP's problem of **test**s being ignored. I've removed the link to my own question.

Comment: Righto, fair enough. Your post came up in the "first post" queue where users with enough rep can review first posts from new users. I wasn't sure if this was just a bunch of random crap that a surprising amount of new users post or useful information. I can now see it's the latter :D